# Python Tkinter Text on same row different column doesn't line up

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQbdz.png]

This happened after adding dropdown boxes and spinners. The text is a little off, on some too far too the left, on others the vertical space isn't uniform. Anyone have a similar issue or solution?

Note: The text on the left side is to show that it doesn't line up, but because off my work, it's purpously cut off.

Here's the code

```
        test[iii].spinner = tki.Spinbox(frame, from_=0, to=test[iii].maxVal)
        test[iii].spinner.grid(row=iii, column = 1)
        test[iii].spinner.delete(0,"end")
        test[iii].spinner.insert(0,test[iii].minVal)

        tki.Label(frame,text=test[iii].label).grid(sticky = "W", row=iii, column = 0)
        tki.Label(frame,text=" Mission Number: ").grid(sticky = "W", row=iii, column = 2)
        test[iii].spinner = tki.Spinbox(frame, from_=0, to=999999999)
        test[iii].spinner.grid(row=iii, column = 3)


        tki.Label(frame,text=test[iii].label).grid(sticky = "W", row=iii, column = 0)
        tki.Label(frame,text=test[iii].comment).grid(sticky = "W", row=iii, column = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `.grid()`. I have not tested this yet, however if you use

`.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky=W)`

it should work.

Comment: I was using a grid. Sorry, I had to get permission to post my code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the text size is smaller than the cell and it is positioned at a non desired location inside it.

You could try fixing it with `ipadx` and `ipady`, two `.grid()` and `.pack()` attributes that do horizontal and vertical internal padding. These attributes can position the cell content in a different location inside it.